# Javascript Workday Progress Bar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to develop a progress bar which gets filled by the amount of time that has passed in two shifts at work.

The first one starts from **7:00 am** to **17:00 pm** and the second one is from **17:00 pm** to **2:00 am** from the next day.

I investigated and found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tePc3/24/) fiddle.
in this part:

```
  $self.prev(".percent").text("0%");
  $.ease(0, targetVal, 10000, "swing", function (i) {
  $self.progressbar("option", "value", parseInt(i));
  $self.prev(".percent").text(parseInt(i) + "%");
```

The problem is that it fills the progress bar continuously, but I need it to stop the progress bar when there are lunch breaks, (9:30am to 10:00am, and 12:00pm to 12:30pm by example, in the first shift) and I truly don't know how to do it.

Which is the best approach possible to do it? I tried to convert the working hours to minutes (substracting the lunch breaks) but it still is incorrect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where's the rest of the code, from which you determine the value of `targetVal`? That's what's going to need to be modified. I presume it parses the current time somehow?

Comment: Oh, if you open the fiddle I referenced there's the full code from where I extract that part. :)

Comment: You want to display the time that has passed between two shifts. Where does the time come from? Do you read it from a database? Is it the current time minus the start of the shift? How is it determined? Note that this asks nothing about the progress bar, and everything about what the data source is, and what the bounds are for that data field.